# How can i specify a appengine devserver port from within eclipse run configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

My configuration: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1) on linux (debian), and apache maven 3.2

My port 8080 is busy, therefore i want to run my devserver for my appengine development on port 8888. I know I can edit the pom.xml file (that come with a couple of projects that I look at), and when i run maven manually, that will start the devserver correctly on the new port, but from within eclipse it will still fail and try 8080. Why does it ignore the pom.xml? What do i need to do to change the run configuration of this maven project to use port 8888?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:
In the run configuration of my maven build, i add a new paramenter/value pair like this:
Parametern Name is appengine.port
Value is 8888

This will start the devserver on port 8888. [image: This is a screenshot of the window, where I added the parameter/value pair.]